# Can't emulate ionic project on android

Tags: ionic-framework

Im new to Ionic dev , im trying to emulate an ionic app on android virtual machine , i installed cordova, node , and the android platfrom for my project . Now when i type : `ionic cordova emulate android`
i get this on the cmd :

```
> cordova emulate android
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Louay Baccary\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova emulate android exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

this is the output after typing `ionic info` on my cmd:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.10.3 (C:\Users\Louay Baccary\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.12.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.2.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : not available

System:

   NodeJS : v10.15.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 10
```

I tried to run cmd as an administrator also , tried to check the android sdk manager , i fully updated my android studio but i still get the same result.

Comment: Please post your `ionic info` output, seems like it might be a problem with your environment.

Comment: i edited my question